# Question about setting datePicker time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

If you look at the iPhone alarm app I can see that if I don't set the time in the date picker, the alarm is set to the current time.

```
@IBAction func selectAlarm(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        print("date : \(date)")
    }
```

The above code outputs the time set when the datePicker is moved. How to output current time as default without moving datePicker as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
@IBAction func selectAlarm(_ sender: Any) {

  let newDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
  newDatePicker.date = Date()
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
  let currentTime = dateFormatter.string(from: newDatePicker.date)
  print("time : \(currentTime)")

  self.yourTextField.text = currentTime

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the datePicker.date outside the func selectAlarm(), eg: in viewDidLoad()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    datePicker.date = Date()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The date Picker works and gives date even without moving datePicker. I have tested it.
 @IBAction func getCurrentTime() {

```
    var formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY"
    var dd = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date) 
    print(dd)
}
```

Problem is with your code.